# modal window redirect

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm using modal window in my project for users login. In that window I'm using iframe to show login form.

How do I reload main page (not modal window) if the user is successfully logged?

Comment: What modal window? Using what framework? You need to show some code.

Comment: Please show a code example. A bit more explenation about what you want to do would be handy aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target` attribute on a link, or on the form itself. For example

```
<form target="_parent"....
```

or

```
<a href="..." target="_parent"...
```

This will update the parent of the iframe instead of the iframe. Alternatively you could fire some JavaScript to reload the main page if the login is correct. Something like:

```
parent.location.href = 'loggedin.html'
```